# Is it possible to send email with attachment as .xls using shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, aix

#!/bin/bash

ATTACH1=file.xls
SUBJECT="subject"
FROM=me@domain.com
TO=you@domain.com
CC=them@domain.com
MIME="application/xls" 
FILE=$ATTACH1
boundary="---my-unlikely-text-for-mime-boundary---$$--" 
(cat <
From: $FROM
To: $TO
Subject: $SUBJECT
Date: $(date +"%a, %b %e %Y %T %z")
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="$boundary"

This email has attached the file
--$boundary
Content-Type: $MIME;name="$FILE"
Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="$FILE"

!
) | sendmail -v ${TO}

Comment: Where did you find this script?? Why is there html mixed with bash, the two are usually exclusive.

Comment: no please ignore the html tags.. anyway, is it possible to attach xls file and email it using shell script?

Comment: Yes, using a valid email sending command (on an equally setup server) you can attach anything you like to an email. But to troubleshoot **this** script, you will need to give some more info about the script itself. Where does it come from, how do you execute it?

Comment: Possibly just change to var line to: `ATTACH1="file.xls"`

Comment: But the quotes are equally important.

Comment: @mindas, I cant use mutt because It is not installed in server

Comment: There are other answers apart from `mutt` - just plain `mail` would do, and I believe it comes as a default in most distros.

Comment: You need to be more explicit about what "doesn't work" means. Do you get an error? Does the mail never arrive? Does it arrive corrupted in some way? Does a voice come over the speaker saying "I'm afraid I can't let you do that, Dave."?

Comment: Are you able to install sendEmail - it is much simpler, but can be handy for scripting ease..

Comment: I think you need to extend your email body so it supports `mimetypes` and then you indicate `mimetype=` (something, maybe `xls`). Sorry, I worked this out 10 years ago, but don't have the code anymore. I've seen a few Qs here that mention this, so search here for `sendmail mimetype` (and plural). Hmm, I'll bet there is a `perl` module that will do this, but if you don't know perl, that will take time to get it working. In general, solving this by trial-and-error will take a while. Work with your boss about best tradeoffs on time. Good luck.

Comment: @ mindas I tried:
sendemail -> but error is: sendemail: command not found..
mail -> but error is: mail: Not a recognized flag: a
uuencode -> only .txt and other formats can be sent but not .xls
all other solutions in the  'How do I send a file as an email attachment using Linux command line' needs to install something first to work...

Comment: @ IMSoP 'doesnt work' means no error when I have executed it but I never received the email :(

Comment: @ asimovwasright I cant install anything on the server.. is sending of email with xls file attachment impossible without installing something?

Comment: @ shelter can you atleast give me some link? I desperately needed it.. please...

Comment: I am still confused how the other file types **did** work. Could you try using the `-m` flag on uuencode, to force base64 encoding instead of default. And please quote the var `ATTACH1="file.xls"`

Comment: Might also consider `ATTACH1="./file.xls"` And according to the uuencode man page, there is no need for output argument, so it should just be `uuencode ${ATTACH1}`
e.g. `tar cf - src_tree | compress | uuencode src_tree.tar.Z | mail sys1!sys2!user`

Comment: Also I just noticed that you have an extra delimiter for the here documents, I don't think there should be the last `!` after the uuencode line, since both here docs are already ended prior to that.

Comment: @asimovwasright Thank you for your response.. I have searched other methods how to send xls file, and the resolution was to add mimetype on the script. 

but I still have a problem.. I cannot read the file that was sent.. also it's file size has been decreased..

How can I open a this file now?

Comment: mmmmm, decreased by how much?

Comment: @asimovwasright The file was originally 17kb but when the file was received it becomes 358bytes only

Comment: open the file as ascii and tell me whats inside

Comment: @asimovwasright it was just blank.. by the way.. I updated the script above

Comment: 358b can't be blank. Did you open it in nano? Also could you give me the output of `file ./new_file_received` where 'new_file_received' of course is the 358b file.

Comment: In the new script, shouldn't the `!` at the end be replaced by `--$boundary`

Comment: uhm..sorry im new to this.. how can I upload the file?

Comment: I don't think you can :-) Do you have a bash shell open on the computer where the file was received?

Comment: yes..can you convert this to chat?
it seems that we cant have a long thread of comments

Comment: I can't move to chat, I don't know why there is no option in this case.

Comment: On the other hand, since you placed your email address in the quesion, would you like me to contact you directly?

Comment: I'll just create another question regarding this.. :)

Comment: Please refer to the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34806131/how-can-i-send-email-with-attachment-xls-file-using-shell-script-as-application

Thank you!